# OVER PARTITION BY sql statement with java EntityManager?

Tags: java, sql, window-functions, jpql, entitymanager

i have a SQL-core statement like this..

```
select * from
    (select isin,  row_number() over (partition by isin order by update_date 
     desc) as ROW_NUMBER
    from stock_job_report where insurer = 'CARDIF' and date = '2021-11-22' 
    order by isin) subrequest
where row_number = 1;
```

specifities of this request are of course :

- using of OVER (PARTITION BY statement
- using of subrequest

how can i do this in java ?
any code snippet ?

Comment: Are you trying to run a query an SQL database using Java? Please explain where the data is, what you have tried and post your code, table definitions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can certainly be run from Java, provided that you run it as a *native* query.  HQL/JPQL does not support analytic functions, since they are specific to databases which support them.

Just to clean up your code a bit:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT isin,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY isin ORDER BY update_date DESC) rn
    FROM stock_job_report
    WHERE insurer = 'CARDIF' AND date = '2021-11-22'
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Note that there is no point at all to having an `ORDER BY` clause in the subuquery.

Comment: your remark is incorrect. the ORDER statement in the subrequest is really important, as i wanna retain, by the upper request WHERE statement only one row. I do not obtain the same row if not.

Comment: No, and your understanding of SQL is incorrect.  `ORDER BY` _never_ changes a result set, only the order.  You end up with a single record result set because of the `WHERE rn = 1` at the end of the query.